# Michael Hartl Ruby Section 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following Hartl's Ruby Tutorial. I'm on the beginning of chapter 5.
   The instructions are to add an image ('rails.png') via

```
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"),
            'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

to the home page at:   app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb

The image is downloaded via

```
$ curl -O http://rubyonrails.org/images/rails.png
$ mv rails.png app/assets/images/
```

However I am receiving an error on the asset precompile. I have no context on how to go about fixing this. So if there's extra info necessary to help solve this problem, let me know so I can add it! 
This is the text of the error page of localhost:3000.

> Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in
>   StaticPagesController#home  Asset was not declared to be precompiled
>   in production. Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(
>   rails.png )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your
>   server
>
> Extracted source (around line #350): def
>   raise_unless_precompiled_asset(path)
>               raise Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled.new(path) unless precompiled?(path)
>             end
>         end
>       end

Edit :   Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.36.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

Comment: Technically you shouldn't need to add an image to precompile, so that's weird. Even so, have you tried adding that code to assets.rb and restarting the server?

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered similar issue a while ago and I've fixed it by adding .png files to precompiled assets. Just try updating your config/application.rb file with following line:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(.png)
```

Please remember about re-starting your Rails server afterwards ;)